# Confused with this implementation of strcpy, why three temp variables is needed?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

**Update: See Eric Postpischil's answer, I think he is right.**

I found it on [this page](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) when I study inline assembly code.

```
static inline char * strcpy(char * dest,const char *src)
{
    int d0, d1, d2;
    __asm__ __volatile__(  "1:\n\t"
                           "lodsb\n\t"
                           "stosb\n\t"
                           "testb %%al,%%al\n\t"
                           "jne 1b"
                           : "=&S" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&a" (d2)
                           : "0" (src),"1" (dest) 
                           : "memory");
    return dest;
}
```

I am confused that why three temp variables is needed? I try to implement without using them.

```
static inline char * strcpy(char * dest,const char *src)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__(  "1:\n\t"
                           "lodsb\n\t"
                           "stosb\n\t"
                           "testb %%al,%%al\n\t"
                           "jne 1b"
                           /* : "=&S" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&a" (d2) */
                           :
                           : "S" (src),"D" (dest) 
                           : "memory", "esi", "edi", "al");
    return dest;
}
```

But I got errors when compile it with gcc.

```
inline.c: In function ‘strcpy’:
inline.c:6:9: error: can't find a register in class ‘SIREG’ while reloading ‘asm’
inline.c:6:9: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code is trying to deal with the fact that the `lodsb` and `stosb` instructions modify registers %ESI, %EDI, and %AL. To do this, it has defined `d0`, `d1`, and `d2` so that it can declare them as outputs from the assembly code. It does not actually want these values as outputs, so it does not use them after the assembly. However, because they are outputs, the compiler knows that they are modified by the assembly code, so the compiler knows not to keep any values in those registers that it wants to remain unchanged through the assembly code.

It should be possible to do this in another way, and your code better expresses the semantics: It says inputs are provided in %ESI and %EDI and that memory, %ESI, %EDI, and %AL are altered. The original code asserts that %ESI, %EDI, and %AL are outputs, which is not the true intent; they are unwanted byproducts, not desired outputs.

However, your version of GCC is different from mine (Apple/clang-418.0.60); mine accepts the code you wrote without error. I suspect your GCC is confused by the fact that %ESI is specified both as an input register (by `"S"` after the second colon) and as something that is clobbered (by `"esi"` after the third colon). Perhaps this was a shortcoming in GCC that was later fixed, and the original code was working around that shortcoming.

Comment: You are right. When I remove the cobbler list, it works fine. :-)

Comment: I suspect removing %ESI and %EDI from the clobber list might allow the code to compile but leave GCC thinking they are used for input but do not change. This does not matter in this isolated `strcpy` that does not use `src` and `dest` again, but suppose it is inlined in code that does. Then GCC might use %ESI or %EDI after he assembly, expecting them to be unchanged.

Comment: There is inline mov_blk(the 4th "Some Useful Recipes" in that page I cite.), it is similar with that strpy(just in the upper side of mov_blk in that page). I got the same error. Some articles say the ecx, esi, edi are not required in the cobberlist in newer version of GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Things are really simple. Lets recall, that `S` constraint stands for `esi`, `a` for `al` and `D` for `edi` register. When you inform compiler, that those guys will be clobbered, you must explicitly point where to spill them (`d0` is temporary storage for `esi`, `d1` for `edi`, `d2` for `al`).

Next in the process of register allocation, compiler decides if he actually need to spill and looks for available register. For example my compiler (gcc 4.7.2) does it as follows:

```
movq  %rdi, %rdx
1:
lodsb
stosb
testb %al,%al
jne 1b
movq  %rdx, %rax
ret
```

You may see, that `d1` was allocated to `rdx`, `d0` and `d2` was eliminated as excessive.

If you don't supply compiler with that information, it can not guess, so outputs error.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You mean the clobbered registers need to be saved? But on my computer, edi, esi have been saved using push.

Comment: Is it enough to put those registers to clobberlist to inform gcc to save them? What's the exact function of the clobberlist?

Comment: Clobber list informs your compiler that something will be clobbered (i.e. unpredictably changed). When doing register allocation, compiler must calculate spill and fill for your clobbered content. There may be spill on stack and fill from it, why not. But to do so for explicitly clobbered register, GCC must associate it with some object with known lifetime and storage class, for example -- local variable like in your case.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin Vladimirov. I think I see. :-)

Comment: Exception is clobbering memory -- this case behaves simply as optimization barrier, making compiler avoid to allocating something that resides in memory to (temporary) registers around this barrier.

Comment: This does not make sense. The original code does not say that %ESI, %AL, or %EDI will be clobbered. They are specified after the first `:`, which means they are specified as outputs, and %ESI and %EDI are also referenced indirectly by the `0` and `1` after the second `:`, which means they are also inputs. They are not listed after the third `:`, which is where clobbered objects that are not outputs may be listed. The compiler is in charge of saving these registers before the assembly; you do not need to provide it objects for that, and that is not what `d0`, `d1`, and `d2` do.

Comment: It does. There are earlyclobber constraints on them